# Get data from xeldocB to ExeldocA

Tags: excel-2010

[image: My 2 documents]
Hi I have a excel sheet that I wants to populate with info  about how many vCPU and Vram a host/published citrix xenap server desktop uses.

Example: In excel1.xlx I want to take the value from excel1:I3 (VMHOSTNAME0) and find the corresponding  cell in pool7.xls (will be A2 in this case) and copy the value from pool7:D column (D2 with the value 4 in this case) and put in excel1:C3

J column and to the right are not important sins they are clones of the ones in I and have the same spec. Storage I might skip for now sins sins number does not reflect the actual used storage.

Note: pool7.xls is a csv file generated from a bash script on a xenserver and might be updated from time to time. I will generate several these documents.

Comment: 2 documents are unnecessary. I can just as well copy the data in to extra sheets in the original doc sins the data is fairly static.

Answer (score 0):

Please open pool7,xls and in the same session try, in C3 of exel1.xlsx copied across to D3 and C3:D3 copied down to suit:

```
=VLOOKUP($I3,[pool7.xls]Sheet2!$A:$E,COLUMN()+1,0)
```